# Can't finish installation of application on Windows 2000?

Tags: installation, process, windows-2000

Why do some program not complete their installation on Windows 2000?

I don't get any error messages in Windows. Is there anything I can do to complete the installation?

Comment: It would help if you can add more details about the application your training to install.

Comment: If there are no messages how do you know they haven't completed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest Windows Installer software on that W2K PC?

Get it here.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=889482fc-5f56-4a38-b838-de776fd4138c&displaylang=en

Answer (score -1):

I have the same on my XP SP3. Oftentimes, the installation screen just gets nonresponsive at some time, with many different programs. I might have messed my Windows up at some point in the past. What sometimes works is just rebooting and doing a repair install. Or, if the installation process has dependent processes, shutting down one of those in task manager - sometimes a program's installation tries to install DirectX too, and will go on if I shut down the DirectX part. Try this only if your installation window is totally unresponsive, don't do it as long as there is a chance that installation might continue; for this might destabilize your PC.

Comment: It's highly inadvisable to just terminate something like a DirectX installer mid-flow, you may end up with a half updated framework, which is really *not* what you want.

Comment: I know, but the choice I have there is rebooting the PC vs. shutting down one of the non-responsive installation processes. The former includes the latter, so it is worth a try to begin with shutting down processes. I will make it extra clear that this is not an option as long as the installation is responsive.